# How to specify database when submit a data lake job from Powershell?

Tags: azure-data-lake

the cmdlet Submit-AzureRmDataLakeAnalyticsJob doesn't have an option to allow database. do we have to hard code the database in script? I want to run my script on different databases.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, today when using Azure PowerShell, CLI, SDK, or REST API, you have to hardcode the database that you'd like to use in the script, if it is different from the default database.